# FirebaseError: Could not parse auth token -7

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am trying to apply custom authentication token which recevied from my server on signup/login with firebase to fetch data from firebase DB. However, I am getting below error on authentication call to firebase.

```
FirebaseError: Could not parse auth token.

{"t":"d","d":{"r":1,"b":{"s":"invalid_token","d":"Could not parse auth token."}}}
```

Below is my code

```
private void checkForDataRead() {
    authFirebaseRef = new Firebase(ApiConstants.FIREBASE_MY_URL);
    authFirebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(AppConstants.FBT, authResultHandler);
    letsFetch();
}

private void letsFetch() {
    authFirebaseRef.getRoot().child("sos/emergengyServicesName").addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.v("onDataChange", ":" + dataSnapshot.child("emergencyServicesName").getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.v("DatabaseError", firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

Firebase.AuthResultHandler authResultHandler = new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
        Log.v("onAuthenticated", authData.getUid());
        letsFetch();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.v("onAuthenticationError= ", "FirebaseError= " + firebaseError.toString());
    }
};
```